# fragment slide transition not as smooth as activity transition

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, transition

When I do `transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.move_left_in, R.anim.move_left_out)`, instead of sliding the fragment out: the window first remove the view child views and then slide. This makes for a poor user experience. What I want is for the view and all its children intact to simply slide out. I am using the same transition for activities and it works fines; no funny attenuation before sliding. How might I get the fragment transition to behave more like the activity transition?

```
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.move_left_in, R.anim.move_left_out);
transaction.replace(R.id.holder, fragment, MyFragment.class.getSimpleName());
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Do your fragments have child fragments?

Comment: Yes, but the child fragment does not contribute to the views: i.e. it comes and goes on demand. More specifically, the child fragment brings up a window when needed and then is dismissed. So when I transition only the main fragment's views are visible.